# More spacing between columns in a table

Tags: tables, spacing, threeparttable

I would like to have more spacing between the column AIC and BIC such that the minus sign in the column BIC does not overlap the numbers in the column AIC. How can I fix this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, bm}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{float, booktabs, makecell, caption, tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\caption{\textbf{Log-likelihood and information criteria of the Nelson-Siegel models}}
\label{table:loglikelihood_aic}
\footnotesize
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTminimum}{\linewidth}
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{8}{S[table-format=1.1]} @{}}
\toprule
\hline 
& {Log-likelihood}   & {\# parameters} & & {AIC} & & {BIC} &  {LR-stat. (DNS)} & {LR-stat. (MS-DNS)} \\ 
\midrule
DNS      & 4239.95  & 18 & & -8443.91  & & -8372.24 &          &          \\
MS-DNS   & 4930.78  & 20 & & -9821.55  & & -9741.93 & 1381.66  &          \\
MS-DRA   & 5067.14  & 38 & & -10058.28 & & -9906.98 & \times   & 272.72   \\
MS-TVTP  & 5012.43  & 26 & & -9972.85  & & -9869.34 & \times   & 163.30   \\
MS-DNS-X & 5148.40  & 44 & & -10208.80  & & -10033.62 & \times   & \times   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\smallskip

\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize\smallskip
 \item Note: This table presents log-likelihood values, the number of parameters, the Akaike information criterion (AIC) and Bayesian information criterion (BIC) for the DNS model and its regime-switching (macro) extensions. In the fifth and sixth column, I present likelihood-ratio test statistics (\textit{LR-stat.}) of the regime-switching models against the DNS model, and of the regime-switching macro models against the MS-DNS model, respectively. \par 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why did you specify `*{8}{S[table-format=1.1]}` for  the data columns?

Comment: Beside that  some like `S[table-format=5.2]` seem more reasonable al least for these two columns, for the love of God, do you really need to show two decimals for numbers near of ten thousands? What valuable information is lost if you show rounded the Aikake Information Criterion?

Comment: @Mico There was no particular reason I chose for `*{8}{S[table-format=1.1]}` for the data columns. I copied the table format from another similar table.

Comment: @Fran You are probably right that one or no decimals is more than appropriate in this case. I will change this for sure.

Comment: Why use `\hline` after `\toprule`? It's... ugly! :-/ Besides, your document doesn't compile (`\times` is only valid in math mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily, changing the specifications for the `S` columns, and using `makecell` to have multiline column heads where necessary:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, bm}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{float, booktabs, makecell, caption, tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb!]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\caption{\textbf{Log-likelihood and information criteria of the Nelson-Siegel models}}
\label{table:loglikelihood_aic}
\footnotesize
\sisetup{table-format=-5.2, table-number-alignment=center}
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=4.2]c*{2}{S}S[table-format=4.2]S[table-format=3.2] @{}}%
\toprule
\midrule[0.4pt]
& {\makecell{Log-\\likelihood}} & {\makecell{n\textsuperscript{o}\,of \\parameters}} & {AIC} & {BIC} & {\makecell{LR-stat.\\ (DNS)}} & {\makecell{LR-stat.\\ (MS-DNS)}} \\
\midrule
DNS & 4239.95 & 18 & -8443.91 & -8372.24 & \\
MS-DNS & 4930.78 & 20 & -9821.55 & -9741.93 & 1381.66 & \\
MS-DRA & 5067.14 & 38 & -10058.28 & -9906.98 & $ \times $ & 272.72 \\
MS-TVTP & 5012.43 & 26 & -9972.85 & -9869.34 & $ \times $ & 163.30 \\
MS-DNS-X & 5148.40 & 44 & -10208.80 & -10033.62 & $ \times $ & $ \times $ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize\smallskip
 \item Note: This table presents log-likelihood values, the number of parameters, the Akaike information criterion (AIC) and Bayesian information criterion (BIC) for the DNS model and its regime-switching (macro) extensions. In the fifth and sixth column, I present likelihood-ratio test statistics (\textit{LR-stat.}) of the regime-switching models against the DNS model, and of the regime-switching macro models against the MS-DNS model, respectively. \par
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]